# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Here is my proof but I ma not so sure about the well-definedness portion of the proof.

I would greatly appreciate anyone verify my results!

Suppose a $p$th root of unity. Then, it is of the form $e^{2\pi i \dfrac{p}{q}}$ 
                    such that $gcd(p,q)=1$. 
                    We define $\phi: \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ 
                    by $\phi(\dfrac{p}{q}+\mathbb{Z}) =  e^{2\pi i \dfrac{p}{q}}$ where $(p,q)=1$.

We show $\phi$ is well-defined. 
                    Suppose $a + \mathbb{Z} = b + \mathbb{Z}$. $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$.
                    Then, since every coset of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ contains exactly one 
                    representative $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ in the range $0 \leq q < 1$,
                    $a + \mathbb{Z} = (p_1/q_1) + \mathbb{Z}$ for some unique $p_1/q_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$
                    such that $0 \leq p_1/q_1 < 1$.
                    Also, $b + \mathbb{Z} = (p_2/q_2) + \mathbb{Z}$ for some unique $p_2/q_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$.
                    Then, it must be $p_1/q_1 = p_2/q_2$. 
                    Hence, $\phi(a+\mathbb{Z}) = \phi(p_1/q_1 + \mathbb{Z}) = \phi(p_2/q_2 + \mathbb{Z})
     = \phi(b + \mathbb{Z})$. 
                    Thus, $\phi$ is well-defined.

We show $\phi$ is homomorphism. 
                    Suppose $p_1/q_1, p_2/q_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then, 
                    \begin{align*}
     \phi( ((p_1/q_1) + \mathbb{Z}) ((p_2/q_2)+ \mathbb{Z}) ) 
      &= \phi( (p_1/q_1 + p_2/q_2) + \mathbb{Z} ) \\
      &= e^{2 \pi i (p_1/q_1 + p_2/q_2)} \\
      &= e^{2 \pi i (p_1/q_1)} \cdot e^{2 \pi i (p_2/q_2)} \\
      &= \phi(p_1/q_1 + \mathbb{Z}) \phi(p_2/q_2 + \mathbb{Z})
     \end{align*}
                    Hence, $\phi$ is homomorphism.

We show $\phi$ is surjective. 
                    Take $e^{2 \pi i (p/q)} \in C^{\times}$. Then, $\phi( (p/q) + \mathbb{Z}) = e^{2 \pi i (p/q)}$.
                    Hence, $\phi$ is surjective.

Lastly, we show $\phi$ is injective. $ker(\phi) = \mathbb{Z}$ since 
                    $e^{2 \pi i (p/q)} = 1$ if and only if $p/q \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence, $ker(\phi)$ is trivial and 
                    $\phi$ is thus injective.

Thus, $\phi$ is an isomorphism. This completes the proof.

Comment: It's cleaner to not bother with well-definedness. Just take the homomorphism $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ given by $r \mapsto e^{2 \pi i r}$ and show that it has image the roots of unity and has kernel $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Your proof seems alright but could be greatly shortend by doing as suggested above. Note that: (a) For well-definedness one can simply show that $a+\mathbb{Z} = b +\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $a-b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and hence $\phi(a+\mathbb{Z}) = e^{2\pi i a} = e^{2\pi i (a-b) + 2 \pi i b}=e^{2\pi i(a-b)} e^{2\pi i b}=e^{2 \pi i b}=\phi(b+\mathbb{Z})$; (b) On your third last line the first instance of $\mathbb{Z}$ should be replaced by $\{\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: Now I see. Thank you so much.